# Insert Edit Windows Forms database in C# Identity Insert Set to Off

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, insert, edit

I'm attempting to create a function to insert and edit button for database. I have a design of 3 text boxes First Name, Last Name, and Address. I set the ID column to Identity true to auto populate the ID number. When attempting to insert getting an exception Identity insert set to off when attempting to insert. For edit I am getting an error "cannot access a disposed product". Now program won't build. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Week4_2_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Inserts Records
        {
            using (objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext())
            {
                TblSoccer name = new TblSoccer
                {
                    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                    LastName = textBox2.Text,
                    Address = textBox1.Text,
                };

                objcontxt.TblSoccers.InsertOnSubmit(name);

                objcontxt.SubmitChanges();
            }

            getAllRecords();
        }

        private void getAllRecords() //Show all records
        {
            using (objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext())
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = objcontxt.TblSoccers;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getAllRecords();
        }

        private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            update_data();
        }

        public void update_data()
        {
            try
            {
                TblSoccer tbl = objcontxt.TblSoccers.Single(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text));
                tbl.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                objcontxt.SubmitChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Updated!!!");
                getAllRecords();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning the project and Rebuild. Check if it works after that.

Comment: thanks. I ended up deleting my connection string which caused quite a bit of issues. Once I fixed that I can now focus on the exception errors.